# Heroku scheduler command not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a node js project at heroku
And it work fine.
I want to make specific function that run on scheduler (every sunday and wensday)
The problem is:
I use heroku scheduler
And set the command
Node createLottery.js
Just to make sure in my terminal its working
So the problem is only with the heroku scheduler

edit:
i now show you the logs from heroku
it looks like the scheduler not working sometime it mean that in 10 pm it wont start my file but sometime it does starting the file
i think its because i have a dyno with sleeping time so maybe the current heroku project is at sleep and it wont start it as should be
i do know when i run the app and use it at 9pm the scheduler working
so maybe it because when the heroku project is active and not sleeping he can run this command
maybe at the first line at the code of the file should i run any fetch to the heroku server to awake him and then it will run as should be?

```
const LotteryModel = require("./models/LotteryModel");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
const currentDate = () => {
  const date = new Date();
  const day = date.getDate();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
};

const createNumbers = () => {
  let tempArr = [];
  let randomNumber;
  let specialNum = { number: Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1, special: true };
  if (specialNum.number === 0) specialNum = { number: Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1, special: true };
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let add = true;
    randomNumber = { number: Math.floor(Math.random() * 36) + 1, special: false };

    for (let y = 0; y < 36; y++) {
      if (tempArr[y]?.number == randomNumber.number) {
        add = false;
      }
    }
    if (add) {
      tempArr.push(randomNumber);
    } else {
      i--;
    }
  }
  tempArr.push(specialNum);
  return tempArr;
};

const createTime = async () => {
  console.log("starting function");
  const currentTime = currentDate();
  const currentDay = new Date().getDay();
  const findLottery = await LotteryModel.findOne({ lotteryDate: currentTime });
  if (findLottery) return;
  if (currentDay === 0 || currentDay === 3) {
    console.log("starting day");
    const allLottery = await LotteryModel.find({});
    const lotteryNumbers = { lotteryNumbers: createNumbers(), lotteryDate: currentTime, id: allLottery.length };
    console.log(lotteryNumbers)
     console.log("middle");
    await LotteryModel.create(lotteryNumbers);
    console.log('finish create numbers')
  }
};
createTime();
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the scheduler user doesn't know the command `heroku`.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler runs commands on a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) that has access to your application code. You don't need to use `heroku run` in that environment (and as you have discovered, the Heroku CLI is not available there).

Instead of

```
heroku run node createLottery.js
```

use

```
node createLottery.js
```

Comment: I dont write heroku run i write node createLottery.js and its give me this error

Comment: Are you using Docker to deploy your code? If you have any of the following files, please edit them into your question as a [code block] (not a screenshot): `Dockerfile`, `heroku.yaml`, `Procfile`, `package.json`.

Comment: hey i upload an update from the issue 
hope someone will help 
thanks